# Android Studio SDK & System Image installation issue

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-emulator

I've been trying to install / update my SDKs and system images from Android Studio's SDK Manager but I'm getting the following error that I could find from a Log. The thing to mark is here that Android Studio is looking for some path that isn't in my system, i.e. my system has path `C:\Users\vidit\` whereas in the error log the path that android logs is `C:\Users\IDSAlpha~1\`

1. How is Android trying to search a path that was never a part of my
   system?
2. What should I do?

`2018-05-04 17:14:05,713 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - To install: 
    2018-05-04 17:14:05,713 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - - Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image (system-images;android-24;google_apis;x86) 
    2018-05-04 17:14:05,713 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - - Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image (system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86_64) 
    2018-05-04 17:14:05,713 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger -

    2018-05-04 17:14:05,713 [ thread 19]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Preparing "Install Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image (revision: 22)". 
    2018-05-04 17:14:05,732 [ thread 19]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86-24_r22.zip 
    2018-05-04 17:14:06,043 [ thread 19]   WARN - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86-24_r22.zip':`
**C:\Users\IDSALP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation07\x86-24_r22.zip (The system cannot find the path specified)**
    , response: 200 OK. 
    java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86-24_r22.zip': **C:\Users\IDSALP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation07\x86-24_r22.zip (The system cannot find the path specified)**, response: 200 OK

```
at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.saveToFile(HttpRequests.java:366)
    at com.intellij.util.io.RequestBuilder.lambda$saveToFile$1(RequestBuilder.java:67)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.lambda$doProcess$0(HttpRequests.java:418)
    at com.intellij.util.net.ssl.CertificateManager.runWithUntrustedCertificateStrategy(CertificateManager.java:349)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.doProcess(HttpRequests.java:418)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.process(HttpRequests.java:398)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$100(HttpRequests.java:63)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestBuilderImpl.connect(HttpRequests.java:266)
    at com.intellij.util.io.RequestBuilder.saveToFile(RequestBuilder.java:67)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.StudioDownloader.downloadFully(StudioDownloader.java:65)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.BasicInstaller.doPrepare(BasicInstaller.java:70)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.prepare(AbstractPackageOperation.java:306)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.preparePackages(InstallTask.java:217)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.run(InstallTask.java:102)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:713)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:543)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:488)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\IDSALP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation07\x86-24_r22.zip (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.saveToFile(HttpRequests.java:361)
    ... 26 more
2018-05-04 17:14:06,043 [ thread 19]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - "Install Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image (revision: 22)" failed. 
2018-05-04 17:14:06,043 [ thread 19]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Preparing "Install Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image (revision: 13)". 
2018-05-04 17:14:06,059 [ thread 19]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86_64-25_r13.zip 
2018-05-04 17:14:06,391 [ thread 19]   WARN - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86_64-25_r13.zip': C:\Users\IDSALP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation01\x86_64-25_r13.zip (The system cannot find the path specified)
, response: 200 OK. 
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86_64-25_r13.zip': C:\Users\IDSALP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation01\x86_64-25_r13.zip (The system cannot find the path specified)
, response: 200 OK
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.saveToFile(HttpRequests.java:366)
    at com.intellij.util.io.RequestBuilder.lambda$saveToFile$1(RequestBuilder.java:67)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.lambda$doProcess$0(HttpRequests.java:418)
    at com.intellij.util.net.ssl.CertificateManager.runWithUntrustedCertificateStrategy(CertificateManager.java:349)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.doProcess(HttpRequests.java:418)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.process(HttpRequests.java:398)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$100(HttpRequests.java:63)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestBuilderImpl.connect(HttpRequests.java:266)
    at com.intellij.util.io.RequestBuilder.saveToFile(RequestBuilder.java:67)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.StudioDownloader.downloadFully(StudioDownloader.java:65)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.BasicInstaller.doPrepare(BasicInstaller.java:70)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.prepare(AbstractPackageOperation.java:306)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.preparePackages(InstallTask.java:217)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.run(InstallTask.java:102)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:713)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:543)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:488)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\IDSALP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation01\x86_64-25_r13.zip (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.saveToFile(HttpRequests.java:361)
    ... 26 more
2018-05-04 17:14:06,391 [ thread 19]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - "Install Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image (revision: 13)" failed. 
2018-05-04 17:14:06,391 [ thread 19]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Preparing "Uninstall Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image (revision: 7)". 
2018-05-04 17:14:06,422 [ thread 19]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - "Uninstall Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image (revision: 7)" failed. 
2018-05-04 17:14:06,422 [ thread 19]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Failed packages: 
2018-05-04 17:14:06,422 [ thread 19]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - - Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image (system-images;android-24;google_apis;x86) 
2018-05-04 17:14:06,422 [ thread 19]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - - Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image (system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86_64) 
2018-05-04 17:14:06,422 [ thread 19]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - - Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image (system-images;android-24;default;x86_64)
```

Comment: just a quick guess is that can you check IDSALP~1 this is the actual folder name in your system? I don't think you can use `~` this sign as a folder name in windows

Comment: @SabaJafarzadeh I'm 100% sure that IDSAlp~1 is not a username or any folders' name in my system.